# Flow errors with enum types on a parameter despite body being valid

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am trying to understand why flow won't accept this as a valid annotation for a series of disjoint union types. From what I can gather it seems valid - clearly, the eventData shape matches both use cases but it is not happy the with the two "types" despite them both being valid.

Any advice on how I could structure this such that it won't have this error would be well appreciated.

```js
type EventOne = {
  types: "my.event.name",
  eventData: {
    c: string,
    v: number
  }
}

type EventTwo = {
  types: "my.second.event.name",
  eventData: {
    c: string,
    v: number
  }
}

type EventThree = {
  types: "this.one.is.very.different",
  eventData: {
    x: number,
    d: number
  }
}

type AnalyticEvent = EventOne | EventTwo | EventThree;

const trackEvent = (payload: AnalyticEvent) => ({
  type: "something",
  payload
});

const makeTrack = (types: "my.event.name" | "my.second.event.name") => {
  trackEvent({
    types,
    eventData: {
      c: "1",
      v: 1
    }
  })
}

makeTrack("my.second.event.name");
```

I have an example in flow try for ease of use:
https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsA8o6BeKBvAUFKUSAZwC4oAiAWxADoIFlbEBDKiCgGnygaWAAiLYC3J4CBAMbliwAE4BLRAHNuEqHHKIArlQBGEOTwC+uU7iLR4-ACoB3APZQs4wuAhlKNWsQiSHiAAm9IzAzGwcaryhQiJiPFIy8kqqCRpaugZGBKbmlrChNgAWchCYODyWnhTARQrEtAEQtPW0CHJ0gQoAZt2G-Fw8fMixohXqAB4Z+oZRBIHTWSZmuBbuUACCrAA2IMAKktbIzgX8aNAAPqfI9k5XR8DFpRAA3Kv+iLKEciySANYPE4ACjALBA2wcLAWmx2ewODwAlM4AHxQIGuSzkCjEBzsWopQYEUHgyGBMwIt64D5fKgsP4QGw-f7AqpY7zDMKsdgUKBXah0XwfYIc8LcpEYVEYpkA0LotJVObRfijeLqRKUACMhLVmigGrSphyCJWuFp9MZvz+QP5Pj8AWFoVFHApQA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear in mind that Flow is a static analyser, and therefore can't track the contents of a variable at runtime (or at least does so in limited circumstances).

The `trackEvent` function call would count as a [refinement invalidation](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#toc-refinement-invalidations), but its not the reason why its failing.

I think this is a weakness, but you can get around it by applying a type refinement, then using a literal.  There is some obvious redundancy there that can be refactored.

```
const makeTrack = (types: "my.event.name" | "my.second.event.name") => {
  if (types === "my.event.name") {
    trackEvent({
      types: "my.event.name",
      eventData: {
        c: "1",
        v: 1
      }
    })
  } else {
    trackEvent({
      types: "my.second.event.name",
      eventData: {
        c: "1",
        v: 1
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. It seems there's really just no other way around it. Cheers